# Windows VS Linux when it comes to Internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, dns, router

In my home the computers running Windows have no problem connecting to the WiFi we pay. *However*, my Ubuntu 14.04 fail to connect every 2-3 days. A reset of the router solves the issue, but that's very annoying for many reasons.

I have focused on this part from `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.485193] wlan0: deauthenticating from 38:22:9d:c5:ca:8c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.506151] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.512504] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.512514] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.512518] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_tim$
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.512527] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.512534] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.512540] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.512546] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jun  1 20:39:22 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  283.512552] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jun  1 20:39:24 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  286.334965] wlan0: authenticate with 38:22:9d:c5:ca:8c
Jun  1 20:39:25 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  286.706803] wlan0: send auth to 38:22:9d:c5:ca:8c (try 1/3)
Jun  1 20:39:25 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  286.708593] wlan0: authenticated
Jun  1 20:39:25 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  286.710501] wlan0: associate with 38:22:9d:c5:ca:8c (try 1/3)
Jun  1 20:39:25 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  286.732307] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 38:22:9d:c5:ca:8c (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
Jun  1 20:39:25 gsamaras-A15 kernel: [  286.732545] wlan0: associated
```

Does anyone please know what can be the issue?

---

Output of `lspci -v`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20ca
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20c5
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20ca
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at f7d0a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20ca
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7d08000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20de
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: dfb00000-dfcfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000dfd00000-00000000dfefffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f7c00000-f7cfffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f0100000-f04fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20ca
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7d07000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20ca
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20ca
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7d06000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20ca
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 4
    Memory at f7d05000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE139H Half-size Mini PCIe Card
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 0123
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: You did not mention what hardware do you have. So the question is not answerable.

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't know that this would affect, sorry! I will update, what info do you want me to report? :)

Comment: Please post the output of lspci -v

Comment: More likely then not it is due to the Realtec driver for your wireless. See if the problem persists with the most recent kernel (Ubuntu 16.04), or file a bug report. A google search on my part did not identify a solution. The alternate is to use a linux compatible wireless USB, you can get them for as little as $10 ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen from that `More likely then not it is due to the Realtec driver for your wireless.` I should understand that the answer posted is not correct? Thanks for the tips..

Comment: dobey which answer is correct? The one is accepted but it has 0 score, while the other has 1. The answer here is delete, so I can't ask @ILOVEKODI about it. Also should I apply that now (that everything seems fine)?

Comment: @ILOVEKODI I do not want to update my Kernel now (too many software installations that are on fire now). In the suggested duplicate, there are two answers, one of Dumindu Mahawela and of mchid and they are different, which one should be followed?

Comment: I would follow the bottom answer. I voted up the one I agree with

Comment: @ILOVEKODI unfortunately I wasn't able to complete his answer. I commented there...I followed the accepted answer and I also did a reboot. I had to reset the rooter again, fingers crossed...

Comment: Generally, reinstalling is unlikely to solve the problem, good luck.

Comment: @ILOVEKODI below every answer you will find a "share" link. Click it to get a link which will directly lead to the answer. I love kodi too btw ;)

Comment: @MadMike thanks for the info! Still learning all the ins and outs of the site

Comment: Please follow the instructions here and please post the info as your driver is most likely not the issue. Any issues with this driver have since been fixed. http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I have been using this driver and this card (multiple different cards of the same type) for years now. I can say that it works great after applying all dist-upgrades.

Comment: I think you need to run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and then reboot. There were issues with this driver on 14.04 but these issues were fixed on subsequent kernel updates. If the problem still persists, you are more than likely on a crowded frequency and need to change your wifi router settings to broadcast on a less crowded frequency. Again, please follow these instructions to help us diagnose the actual issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: Also, see  here http://askubuntu.com/questions/482170/asus-pce-ac66-bcmwl-kernel-source-unstable-connection-with-frequent-disconnec

Comment: @mchid thanks for jumping into my question! WiFi is now stable, if it fails again, I will do so!